# How to connect column to another table column sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem I can't figure out how to connect the MED_ORDER_PRICE in the orders table to the med_price in the medicine table while the med_id is the primary key for the medicine table i tried putting it unique but its a price it couldn't work with the program, and there is an TOTAL_ORDER_PRICE that gets me the ( order_quantity * MED__ORDER_PRICE(from order table), but i need to connect the two columns (med_price AND MED_ORDER_PRICE)from the two tables together to do it, but I tried the foreign key and it returns the med_id into the price.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE MEDICINE
(
    MED_ID NUMBER(10) ,
    MED_NAME VARCHAR2(50) ,
    MED_DESC VARCHAR2(200),
    MED_PRICE decimal(4,2) ,
    MED_CATEGORY NUMBER REFERENCES CATEGORY (CATEGORY_ID) ,
    CONSTRAINT MED_PK PRIMARY KEY(MED_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ORDERS 
(
 ORDER_ID NUMBER ,
 ORDER_DATE DATE NOT NULL, 
 CUST_ORDER_ID NUMBER REFERENCES CUSTOMERS (CUST_ID) ,
 MED_ORDER_ID NUMBER REFERENCES MEDICINE (MED_ID)  ,
 MED_ORDER_PRICE NUMBER (4,2) ,
 ORDER_QUANTITY  decimal(4,2) , 
 TOTAL_ORDER_PRICE  decimal(4,2) AS (MED_ORDER_PRICE*ORDER_QUANTITY),
 CONSTRAINT ORDER_PK PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID)
);

INSERT INTO MEDICINE VALUES(1,'miojesic','it relaxes the HEART muscles',2.60,1);

INSERT INTO MEDICINE VALUES(2,'Advil','it lower the temp and relaxes the brain ',3.60,3);

INSERT INTO MEDICINE VALUES(3,'antidiabetes','it relaxes the stomick',3.50,5);



INSERT INTO MEDICINE VALUES(4,'voltfast','used for teeth problems',1.20,2);                                                                     

INSERT INTO MEDICINE VALUES(5,'penceline','to kill bakterias',2.30,5);

INSERT INTO ORDERS (ORDER_ID,ORDER_DATE,CUST_ORDER_ID,MED_ORDER_ID,MED_ORDER_PRICE,ORDER_QUANTITY)VALUES(1,TO_DATE('1/5/2020','DD/MM/YYYY'),1,3,3.50,4);



INSERT INTO ORDERS (ORDER_ID,ORDER_DATE,CUST_ORDER_ID,MED_ORDER_ID,MED_ORDER_PRICE,ORDER_QUANTITY)VALUES(2,TO_DATE('30/4/2020','DD/MM/YYYY'),2,2,3.60,1);

INSERT INTO ORDERS (ORDER_ID,ORDER_DATE,CUST_ORDER_ID,MED_ORDER_ID,MED_ORDER_PRICE,ORDER_QUANTITY)VALUES(3,TO_DATE('29/4/2020','DD/MM/YYYY'),3,5,2.30,3);

INSERT INTO ORDERS (ORDER_ID,ORDER_DATE,CUST_ORDER_ID,MED_ORDER_ID,MED_ORDER_PRICE,ORDER_QUANTITY)VALUES(4,TO_DATE('28/4/2020','DD/MM/YYYY'),4,1,2.60,2);

INSERT INTO ORDERS (ORDER_ID,ORDER_DATE,CUST_ORDER_ID,MED_ORDER_ID,MED_ORDER_PRICE,ORDER_QUANTITY)VALUES(5,TO_DATE('26/4/2020','DD/MM/YYYY'),5,4,1.20,2);
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desird results.

Comment: OK I EDITED THE POST AND ADDED THE INSERT CODE .

Comment: THE DESIRED DATA IS :- WHEN  THE MED_ID IS ENTERD IN THE MED_ORDER_ID THE MED_ORDER_PRICE WILL CHANGE TO DESIRD (AS THE MED ID) MED_PRICE .

Comment: @GhaithEAlnaimat - using ALL CAPS is the Internet-equivalent of SHOUTING. Please don't do that. And while seeing your data is helpful, anyone wishing to help you will also need to see the code you've written in order to understand the problems you've described. Please edit your question using the `edit` button just below the tags and include your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution to the problem you're facing is to use a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ORDERS_BI
  BEFORE INSERT ON ORDERS
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  nMed_price  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT m.MED_PRICE
    INTO nMed_price
    FROM MEDICINE m
    WHERE m.MED_ID = :NEW.MED_ORDER_ID;

  :NEW.MED_ORDER_PRICE := nMed_price;
END ORDERS_BI;
```

[Trigger db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=af3709f92d424d572c585b5f4f8d4ed3)

Another possibility is to use a MERGE statement which obtains the current MED_PRICE from the MEDICINE table and uses this value to set MED_ORDER_PRICE on ORDERS:

```
MERGE INTO ORDERS o
  USING (SELECT r.ORDER_ID, r.ORDER_DATE, r.CUST_ORDER_ID, r.MED_ORDER_ID,
                r.ORDER_QUANTITY, m.MED_PRICE
           FROM (SELECT 1 AS ORDER_ID, DATE '2020-05-01' AS ORDER_DATE, 1 AS CUST_ORDER_ID, 3 AS MED_ORDER_ID, 4 AS ORDER_QUANTITY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 2, DATE '2020-04-30', 2, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 3, DATE '2020-04-29', 3, 5, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 4, DATE '2020-04-28', 4, 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 5, DATE '2020-04-26', 5, 4, 2 FROM DUAL) r
           INNER JOIN MEDICINE m
             ON m.MED_ID = r.MED_ORDER_ID) d
    ON (o.ORDER_ID = d.ORDER_ID)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE, CUST_ORDER_ID, MED_ORDER_ID, ORDER_QUANTITY, MED_ORDER_PRICE)
    VALUES (d.ORDER_ID, d.ORDER_DATE, d.CUST_ORDER_ID, d.MED_ORDER_ID, d.ORDER_QUANTITY, d.MED_PRICE);
```

[Merge statement db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8df7d7ee92e16042001e75d8567e3773)

Answer (score 0):

At a very simplistic level this is a simple join on medicine to orders on med_id and med_order_id.

```
select m.name, m.desc,m.med_price,o.med_order_price
  from medicine m
  join orders   o
    on m.med_id = o.med_order_id;
```

or even medicine to orders on med_id and med_order_price.

```
select m.name, m.desc,m.med_price,o.med_order_price
  from medicine m
  join orders   o
    on m.med_id = o.med_order_price;
```

That second query doesn't make any since but is perfectly valid according the data model because order.med_order_price is a FK to medicine. 
That relationship is also why your sample data cannot be inserted into the orders table. Taking your first order as an example:

```
+------------------+----------+
|    Column Name   |  Value   |
+------------------+----------+
|  Order_id        | 1        |
|  order_date      | 1/5/2020 |
|  cust_order_id   | 1        |
|  med_order_id    | 3        |
|  med_order_price | 3.50     |
|  order_quantity  | 4        |
+------------------+----------+
```

Now since med_order_price is a FK to Medicine means this row identifies med_id 3.50, this of course does not exist (and can net as med_id is an integer).
So the attempt at inserting this row results in a FK violation. So some table modification is necessary.  
 
But just removing that FK does not resolve all model issues. In addition to removing that FK you should remove the column med_price from Medicine table. Consider a second order for the same medicine resulting in orders:

```
+------------------+----------+----------+
|    Column Name   | Value 1  | Value 6  |
+------------------+----------+----------+
|  Order_id        | 1        | 6        |
|  order_date      | 1/5/2020 | 5/6/2020 |
|  cust_order_id   | 1        | 1        |
|  med_order_id    | 3        | 3        |
|  med_order_price | 3.50     | 4.00     |
|  order_quantity  | 4        | 4        |
+------------------+----------+----------+
```

Now what should be in med_price? Valid values would seem to be any of 3.50, 4.00, 3.75, 14.00, 16.00, 15.00.
You would need much better defineition what that column contains. This this does seem to be derivable value and therefore **should not be stored**. Does that make the whole question mute -- *probably not*.  
Further, two naming conventions: There is no need to repeat the table name on the columns, although tablename_id is good, or to qualify columns where without doing so makes a poor name (here order_date as date is a very poor column name, date is a data type and a reserved word).
Nor is there any reason to 'rename' FK column names, just use the same column name as in the referenced table.
Taking all this we arrive at table definitions as:

```
create table medicine
(
    med_id       number(10) 
  , med_name     varchar2(50)   not null
  , description  varchar2(200)
  , category_id  number         not null  
  , constraint med_pk primary key(med_id)
  , constraint med2category_fk 
               foreign key (category_id) 
               references category(category_id)              
);

create table orders 
(
   order_id        number(10) 
 , order_date      date           not null 
 , cust_id         number         not null 
 , med_id          number(10)     not null  
 , price           decimal(4,2)   not null  
 , quantity        decimal(4,2)   not null 
 , total_price     decimal(4,2)   as (price*quantity) 
 , constraint  order_pk primary key (order_id) 
 , constraint  order2cust_fk 
               foreign_key (cust_id)
               references customer(cust_id) 
 , constraint  orders2med_fk 
               foreign key (med_id)
               references medicine(med_id)                        
);
```

Now we can get all the information together with a simple join on the med_id column in Medicine and Order tables.

```
select m.med_id
     , m.med_name
     , m.description
     , o.order_date
     , o.price
     , o.quantity
     , o.total_price Order_total
     , avg(o.price)       over (partition by o.med_id) Adv_med_price 
     , sum(o.quantity)    over (partition by o.med_id) Total_med_quantity    
     , sum(o.total_price) over (partition by o.med_id) Total_med_price 
  from medicine m 
  join orders   o 
    on (o.med_id = m.med_id)
 order by m.med_id;    

select m.med_id
     , m.med_name
     , m.description
     , count(*)           "Num Orders"
     , avg(o.price)       "Adv Med Price" 
     , sum(o.quantity)    "Total Med Quantity"    
     , sum(o.total_price) "Total Med Price" 
  from medicine m 
  join orders   o 
    on (o.med_id = m.med_id)
 group by m.med_id
        , m.med_name
        , m.description
 order by m.med_id;
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=14ef0df55cb84d5f478467ee56ede99c). (removed FKs med2category_fk and  order2cust_fk  from fiddle as the referenced tables do not exist.)